# goroutines deadlock, need some explanation

Tags: go, deadlock, goroutine

I wanted to understand how does the Go-routine work here.

Question 1:
Does the go-routine inherit anything from the main GO routine/func??

Question 2:
Also wanted to know if I send "hi whats up" into the msg channel why is it not received by the go-routine at LINE:13????

```
  1 package main
  2 
  3 import "fmt"
  4 
  5 func main() {
  6     msg := make(chan string, 2) //channel (bidirectional channel) of type string
  7 
  8     msg <- "hi whats up"
  9     fmt.Println("*****I am main go routine*****")
 10 
 11     go func() {
 12         fmt.Println("*****HI ABHI *****\n")
 13         temp := <-msg
 14         fmt.Println(temp)
 15         msg <- "Hello from a goroutine!" //send a string through the channel
 16     }()
 17 
 18     fmt.Println("Main routine waiting for message")
 19 
 20     fmt.Println(<-msg) //receive the string from the channel
 21     fmt.Println(<-msg)
 22 }
```

Getting following error:

> *****I am main go routine*****
>
> Main routine waiting for message
>
> hi whats up
>
> *****HI ABHI *****
>
> fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
>
> goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
>
> main.main()
>
> /Users//work/go/src/github.com/Golang_play/goroutine/goroutine.go:21
>   +0x1e6
>
> goroutine 5 [chan receive]:
>
> main.main.func1(0xc420054060)
>
> /Users/work/go/src/github.com/Golang_play/goroutine/goroutine.go:13
>   +0x98 created by main.main    /Users/work/go/src/github.com/Golang_play/goroutine/goroutine.go:11
>   +0xe2 exit status 2

Also in the following program LINE 14 never prints.

```
 5 func main() {
  6     msg := make(chan string, 2) //channel (bidirectional channel) of type string
  7 
  8     msg <- "hi whats up"
  9     fmt.Println("*****I am main go routine*****")
 10 
 11     go func() {
 12         fmt.Println("*****HI ABHI *****\n")
 13         temp := <-msg
 14         fmt.Println(temp)
 15         //msg <- "Hello from a goroutine!" //send a string through the channel
 16     }()
```

Comment: Not related to the error (for now) but you are trying to recieve the channel three times while you only try to send 2 messages. That seems pretty wrong.

Comment: The second part of code line 14 never gets a chance to execuate because when main func returns, the go program ends. You can add a simple `time.Sleep(time.Second)` (remember to `import "time"`) after line 16 to see the effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to send messages two ways on the same channel, and you don't do anything to guarantee who reads which messages. It's entirely possible for the main goroutine to receive **the message it sent**, before the `func` goroutine attempts to read from the channel. If that happens, both goroutines get stuck waiting for messages that will never arrive.

Use two channels.

Comment: msg := make(chan string, 2) 


msg <- "hi whats up"

fmt.Println("*****I am main go routine*****")

go func() {

fmt.Println("*****HI ABHI *****\n")

temp := <-msg

fmt.Println(temp)

//msg <- "Hello from a goroutine!" //send a string through the channel

}()

Comment: If look at my comment, I have edited the program, even now the "fmt.Println(temp)" doesn't print

Comment: @Invictus Please edit the code into the question and format it. It is mostly unreadable here.

Comment: @Invictus: The program ends when the main goroutine ends.

Answer (score 1):

The newly started goroutine can capture variables from the outer code via a closure, but otherwise don't inherit anything.

There's a race between the channel receive on line 13 and the one on line 20. If the read on line 20 gets executed first, it'll consume the only value on the channel, and ultimately, both goroutines are blocked reading from a channel, hence the deadlock error. If you want to get a value out of the goroutine back, its better to have another channel rather than trying to sequence it all on the one.

Comment: For point #1, if the new go-routine doesn't inherit from main go-routine then how does the "new go-routine" get the msg channel????

Comment: @Invictus that is what we call "closure". Google it.

Comment: But, I didn't pass the "msg chan" in the closure for the new go-routine, then how did the new go-routine get it???

Comment: @Invictus it is hard to explain the whole concpets of closure here, but simply put, the goroutine, as a function, can access variable of the otter scope, which is the main func.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    msg := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        temp := <-msg
        fmt.Println(temp)
        msg <- "Hello from a goroutine!"
    }()

    msg <- "hi whats up"
    fmt.Println(<-msg)
}
```

With an unbuffered channel, message passing is synchronous, so goroutines never receive messages from themselves (because the same goroutine would have to be sending and receiving at the same time for that to happen). Note that this design requires you to start the goroutine reading from the `msg` channel before writing anything into it, or you'd be stuck waiting for the reader and unable to start it.

Comment: Why would it not work if I write into the msg channel before calling the "go routine"???

Comment: @Invictus in this code, it is because it is unbuffered and nothing reads from it (the goroutine has not started yet).